# why is my node.js app crashing after write after end error

Tags: node.js

So I'm trying go through a 8 hours video tutorial on Node.js and Express but I seem to hit a point where I am not understanding well.

There's a quick example of an app running but my app keeps crashing unlike in the videos that seems to be working fine. The app code is below and my dilemma is after as well as the error message on console.

```
const http = require('http')

const server = http.createServer((req,res)=> {

    if(req.url === '/'){
        res.end('Welcome to our home page')
    }
    if(req.url === '/about'){
        res.end('Here is our short history')
    }

    res.end(`
        <h1>Oops!</h1>
        <p>We can't seem to find the pages you are looking for</p>
        <a href="/">Back Home</a>
        `)

})

server.listen(5000)
```

whenever I start the app in my terminal it starts fine. My problem is that when I go to the browser at **localhost:5000/, localhost:5000/about** my app crashes. If I go to **localhost:5000/error*** it working fine until I click the link that send me to **localhost:5000/** and then crashes again. With the following messages.

```
node:events:504
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error [ERR_STREAM_WRITE_AFTER_END]: write after end
    at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:371:5)
    at ServerResponse.end (node:_http_outgoing:846:15)
    at Server.<anonymous> (/home/chachoz007/NodeJS/tutorial/app.js:12:6)
    at Server.emit (node:events:526:28)
    at parserOnIncoming (node:_http_server:951:12)
    at HTTPParser.parserOnHeadersComplete (node:_http_common:128:17)
Emitted 'error' event on ServerResponse instance at:
    at emitErrorNt (node:_http_outgoing:726:9)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:84:21) {
  code: 'ERR_STREAM_WRITE_AFTER_END'
}
```

Now I get that my app crashes because res.end and the end is trying to write after it already ended in one of the if statements from before.

My problem is why it is crashing compared to the tutorial that i am following that is not crashing. My version of node.js is 16.**** compared to the tutorials version of 14.****

i was wondering if someone could give me some intell on this issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can only call .end() once for each request.

Your code executes the .end() method twice whenever the request is for / or /about; once in the if-else and then a second time after that. One way to solve it is to use "else if" and then else for the final .end() call.